# How to declare type guard dynamically in typescript?

Tags: typescript, intellisense, typescript-typings, typeguards

I want to set type guard dynamically depends on array elements

Working on strategy pattern in typescript. here is the code

```js
class StrategyManager {
  strategies: Strategy[]
  constructor() {
    this.strategies = []
  }

  addStrategy(strategy: Strategy) {
    this.strategies.push(strategy)
  }

  getStrategy(name: <dynamic>) { // this is where I need dynamic type guard
    return this.strategies.find((strategy) => strategy.name === name)
  }
  
}
```

Suppose strategies are added like so:

```js
const sm = new StrategyManager()
sm.addStrategy({name:'foo'})
sm.addStrategy({name:'bar'})
```

Then;

while getting `strategy` using  `sm.getStrategy`. I need `name` parameter of type `'foo' | 'bar'`

Thus intellisense will throw error like so:

```js
sm.getStrategy('baz') // Intellisense error: `Argument of type '"baz"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"foo" | "bar"'`
```

Comment: You want [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAuAnM8CmBzAngWTAOzHVUWgG8BYAKGmgiRQwEtUIAuOetLAbQF0qawAPZ46iAK7B4QxAAoAlGQE1o8ABaMIAOjEN0zGAF5ofZQF8qysABNrCZF0yzdj9vb2ZFFaivWadnEwsWgAO4hBqzoFY8uaWPkTw7o4APABy0KgAHmh41jDJGJjcAOQEALaoJbwAfLIVqOxpXso0iKjw4oh4qhraLkHaAGaMebJRDkXy7ANY0JqqmCGoQkO00ZjQAGRk0A1N0GbQhjXrk1haDceGxg2xPhaUVI-CovC05cd7qADuHOc4fCEYgKKgQcpaRKFLCyEpDIRCEryAD8lzAlXi8CWqH+Hi+pD26Ma0DhCJK0AAPiSAEZgRDksxAA) I believe

Comment: @AluanHaddad little close, can we set `type` using `map` on array instead of hard coded? I think thats what will solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what `map` has to do with it.

Comment: You won't be able to change the typing dynamically like that. What you can do is have the addStrategy method return the StrategyManager instance but with a new signature for the getStrategy method that includes whatever you added. This only helps you if you can add all your strategies before declaring the variable that will hold your Strategy Manager

Comment: can `name` be any string? Or is there a fixed list of possible names that you know at compile time?

Comment: Are you saying that `'foo'` only works because you've called `addStrategy('foo')` prior to `getStrategy('foo')`? If so, then @ChrisBode is correct.

Comment: @AlexWayne name can be anything, but known at compile time

Comment: You need to use some kind of immutable builder pattern if you want the allowed types to depend on each adds.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Ohh.. I get it now, thanks! for the thought on builder pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @ChisBode's comment, you can achieve this if you alter your implementation as follows.

Instead of using a *mutable* object that builds up an array *value* via successive mutations, you can design your strategy manager as an *immutable* object that builds up an array *type* via successive transformations.

Here's a working prototype:

```
class StrategyManager<N extends Strategy['name'] = never> {
  strategies: (Strategy & { name: N })[] = [];

  withStrategy<S extends Strategy>(strategy: S): StrategyManager<N | S['name']> {
    const result = new StrategyManager<N | S['name']>();
    result.strategies = [...this.strategies, strategy];
    return result;
  }

  getStrategy<T extends N>(name: T) {
    return this.strategies.find(
      (strategy): strategy is typeof strategy & { name: T } => strategy.name === name
    );
  }
}


new StrategyManager()
  .withStrategy({ name: 'bar' })
  .getStrategy('foo')?.name // error as desired

new StrategyManager()
  .withStrategy({ name: 'bar' })
  .getStrategy('bar')?.name // ok; typeof name is 'bar' | undefined


new StrategyManager()
  .withStrategy({ name: 'bar' })
  .withStrategy({ name: 'foo' })
  .getStrategy('foo')?.name // ok; typeof name is 'foo' | undefined

type Strategy = { name: 'foo' | 'bar' };
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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)

Notes:

1. Each `withStrategy` call returns a new object with a type that is further refined.
2. The constraint doesn't need to involve the `Strategy` type, it could be an arbitrary `string`.
3. Since we are following an immutable design pattern, we should really ensure that the strategies array underlying the manager cannot be modified via other means. To accomplish this, we can transition from a class to a factory, obtaining hard privacy via closures and reducing the amount of code we have to write as a bonus:

   ```
   function strategyManager<N extends Strategy['name'] = never>(
     strategies: (Strategy & { name: N })[] = []
   ) {
     return {
       withStrategy<S extends Strategy>(strategy: S) {
         return strategyManager<N | S['name']>([...strategies, strategy]);
       },
       getStrategy<T extends N>(name: T) {
         return strategies.find(
           (strategy): strategy is typeof strategy & { name: T } => strategy.name === name
         );
       }
     };
   }

   strategyManager()
     .withStrategy({ name: 'bar' })  
     .getStrategy('foo')?.name // error as desired

   strategyManager()
     .withStrategy({ name: 'bar' })  
     .getStrategy('bar')?.name // ok; typeof name is 'bar' | undefined


   strategyManager()
     .withStrategy({ name: 'bar' })
     .withStrategy({ name: 'foo' })
     .getStrategy('foo')?.name // ok; typeof name is 'foo' | undefined

   type Strategy = { name: 'foo' | 'bar' };
   ```

   [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZygJwIZQKYHMCeAshmBrtmgDwByi2AHjmACbKIDK6We+A2gOSkAttn4BdRAF5EYbADcKAPgAUqTDlwxsyAFyJlndT0QAyRAG8ZGEXtoBfAJS8J05w4sBYAFCJEabFAgaEjm3r6+AO4wUAAWhtwElOx0jNgsbPEa+CpqCfh67O6hPuG+EAioftogADZQUihcWcSk5FS0AD4cAsKiYiq8AHTDuRpayAA0jUYEYg4A3GGlVYHBVci1UIslvnYT3ku+5FCZPJQAKilMrIjUKr1650WH4f6rSKN444PAMCzKqiaPAcek+BEQMDYUHwAAdsHBgNM8qYLFYbIhLnYpIokVlBr0pJJpL0Fi87Es7NtyV5vGCiCQyBRlA4loMorFTgRlJYHoh+AAjDBofiIRys46c-DKfjAOBwfgOAD8+Os2EQAHp1XQ0Gg4GhEBg2MxtDB-MwDl46S1GWhmaz2XEgVyeaq9AKhSKxSVBhKnVL3cKlSqRBqtXAANbzRDQuEItFqyF8wXCxBdcDG36yc00nNWhltO3eh2S7nxt3Jz0sovRR0zKUu9EyuWV8UBEtN+VBgmaxARqMx+GIgmJjsitMsbCZ7DZ7wDjh+hoN7Bu2Xy1NJj2i+ZAA)
4. You could also achieve encapsulation via the [Stage 3 ECMAScript private fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) but closures are supported in more environments and are simple and battle tested.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done as described.

Typescript can't keep track of all possible things you've added, because it doesn't really *run* your code. If any string value can be used at runtime, then typescript cannot possibly help you constrain that type.

What if you had?

```
sm.addStrategy(await getAsyncStrategyFromServer())
```

The type system can't know what what name that will have because it can't be known at compile time. The compiler can't help you with something the compile doesn't know.

---

You have to think of what is a compile time type error, and what is a runtime error.

In this case, at compile time, `string` is the right type anywhere there is a strategy name. This is because, as you say, name can be any string.

But it's a *run time* error if you get a strategy name that has not been added, because strategies are added dynamically *at run time*. Which means you handle that error with logic, and not with the type system.

```
  getStrategy(name: string) {
    const strategy = this.strategies.find((strategy) => strategy.name === name)
    if (strategy) {
      return strategy
    } else {
      // or something.
      throw new Error(`Strategy with name: ${name} not found`)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thats really helpful.